# Polymer vs Angular 2 - Reusing Web Components

Tags: angular, polymer

I see that you can use Polymer Components in an Angular 2 application, but can you use an Angular 2 component in a Polymer application.

I am trying to determine which is more re-usable. I would think that the best way to go would be to build components that are framework independent. And it seems to me that Polymer is exactly that, a cross-framework solution.

Comment: A2 borrows concepts from WC but doesn't provide them. It is supposed to work in one direction. If you're looking for WC implementations, you may probably take a look at Aurelia instead.

Comment: It seems that if Angular 2 would enable the use of Web Components without defining a root module that this might be possible. So basically just have Angular scan the DOM looking for Web Component selector matches. Ugh. I'd like to use Aurelia we are constrained by the customer who says what we can and cant use.

Comment: They decided to jump off WC train quite a while ago, so NgModule was just another step back to A1. Polymer and Aurelia are two major WC-friendly frameworks I'm aware of, so the options are obvious.